# Is there a proper name for the property of isosceles having coinciding heights, median and angular bisector?

Tags: geometry, terminology

I know in an isosceles triangle, the height, median and angular bisector to the base are coincidental by SSS or other congruent theorems, but I searched all over the world and can't find whether there's a name for this property.

Comment: I think its trivial enough to not have a name.

Comment: @AaaLol_dude Though it's used quite often in proofs of basic geometry.

Comment: The fact that we don't have records of the first person that proved this made naming difficult, and the 'elementaryness' of the property in question can be compared to the fact that $\frac{p}{2}$ is almost always not an integer, since there is no theorem on nearly all primes being odd.